# When trying to answer your own question, is the prompt necessary for hi-rep users?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

If I want to answer my own question I have to click a link and then there's a prompt explaining that I should use comments or edits to my question for clarification.

Is this prompt really necessary for users with say 5k+ reputation?

Comment: It could also work if it show only first time for 5k+ user. Yaa and  its annoying

Comment: Especially since the users the prompt is targeted at never read it anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Why look at it from the rep point of view? I see no issue in disabling it for users who have seen it more than two times already, regardless of rep.

I'm saying this because not all high rep users know the rules. Out of those which do, not all have asked (many)questions. For example, my [co-mod](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/qmechanic) has 0 questions despite being high rep. It's a good idea to show that message to everyone, IMO.